# "failed to cast system.datetime to system.char[]" error using oledb and ado.net

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, ssis

I'm extracting about 25 columns/2.5 million rows from a sql server db with an ole db connection, then loading into Teradata with an ado.net connection but keep getting an error "failed to cast system.datetime to system.char[]" - my input/output columns are all set correctly to db_timestamp..

Weird thing is that when I ran all the columns apart from the 6 datetime columns - this was fine.. I then ran only the datetime columns which worked fine as well, but for some reason when I run the package with the whole dataset (the 25 columns) I continually get this error.. At no point am I even trying to cast datetime to a string, is SSIS trying to do this implicitly?

Could it be something to do with making use of the oledb & ado.net together and hitting some sort of data limit? I've spent 2 days trying to figure out the problem.

Comment: Have you checked the datatypes on all the destination columns to see if they match up?

Comment: Knowing nothing of teradata, my first assumption would be that the date/time units are incompatible between the two so behind the scenes, the ado.net driver is updating it to character and then trying to write that to teradata

Comment: Yeah I've checked all the data types they're all good, in teradata the equivalent is TIMESTAMP.. I'm using TIMESTAMP(6), but it's not just as simple as that as when I extract and load all those datetime columns on their own it works perfectly, only when they're in with all the rest of the columns does it error out and pass me that message. I could also load in a customerref field (int) with all the datetime columns and that was fine, it's literally just when I try pushing the whole 25 column dataset through that it fails.. doesn't make any sense does it!?

Comment: Unless going on from what you're saying billinkc, that by including ANY other string columns, the ado.net is automatically applying some sort of implicit string conversion on all of the fields before passing them through to teradata?

Comment: Have you looked at the Attunity drivers for Teradata? http://www.microsoft.com/en-au/download/details.aspx?id=29283#

Comment: I have looked at the attunity driver but the infrastructure is so locked down at work it might be difficult to get it installed.. having said that I may need to since my SSIS packages don't seem to be batch loading through ado.net. On the original issue, I think I have found the problem - I was putting a where criteria in with my original SQL statement excluding data from 3 columns - all varchar, however, I think a data integrity issue has allowed some rows to be entered which SSIS is picking up as datetime, therefore can't convert to string to apply the where clause! thanks a lot for help all